# Expo not hot-reloading from VS Code debugger

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm working on my React Native app in VS Code, with the React Native Tools debugger running on "Debug in Exponent". Live reloading works, but when I enable hot reloading (after disabling live reload), hot reloading doesn't happen.

I'm sure you'd like to see various settings. Not sure what's important so here's some things:

```
// relevant debug config from launch.json
    {
      "name": "Debug in Exponent",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
      "type": "reactnative",
      "request": "launch",
      "platform": "exponent",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }

// .expo/packager-info.json
{
  "devToolsPort": 19002,
  "expoServerPort": 19000,
  "packagerPort": 8081,
  "packagerPid": null,
  "expoServerNgrokUrl": "https://zr-j4p.tuzmusic.tuz1app.exp.direct",
  "packagerNgrokUrl": "https://packager.zr-j4p.tuzmusic.tuz1app.exp.direct",
  "ngrokPid": 5404
}

// .expo/settings.json
{
  "hostType": "lan",
  "lanType": "ip",
  "dev": true,
  "minify": false,
  "urlRandomness": "zr-j4p"
}
```